# Why my many-to-one laravel relationship does not work?

Tags: laravel, relationship, one-to-many

I know this has been asked many times but none of the solutions apply to my issue.
I'm having trouble with one to many relationships (one file can have one status but status can be assigned to many files), it just always returns null when I try to use it as so:

```
$file = File::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->first();
return $file->status;
```

And when I try using the relationship as so:

```
$file = File::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->with('status')->first();
return $file->status;
```

I get an error

```
Call to undefined relationship [status] on model [App\File]
```

I'm sure everything is set up correctly, see models bellow
File.php

```
public function status()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Status', 'status_id');
}
```

"Files" table
[image]

"Statuses" table:

[image]

Also, inverse relationship works (when I try to get files of a specific status)

```
public function files()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\File', 'status_id'); //This works
}
```

Comment: change the name of the function status as getstatus or anything and you will not get the error. Never assign class name as function name it will become construct method.

Comment: execute this command ` composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @A.ANoman Thanks you so much. Thanks to your suggestion I was able to locate the problem. I had a backup "File.php" version called "File_x.php" and that file was being used as File model instead of File.php, very stupid mistake but perhaps this situation might help someone to locate their problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Call to undefined relationship [status] on model [App\File]
```

the error you're getting because of your class name and function name are the same. and when you make this kind of the function and it works like **construct method** function.

```
public function filestatus()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Status', 'status_id');
}


$file = File::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->with('filestatus')->first();
return $file->status;
```

Comment: Still getting the same error, just with filestatus instead of status now....
Call to undefined relationship [filestatus] on model [App\File].

Comment: Is it possible that laravel expects table 'statuses' to be called something else?